# How can I import contacts into a mailbox and overwrite with powershell?

Tags: powershell, csv

so I am new to powershell. I understand some of the basics and am still trying to teach myself as much as I can.

So I have been asked to automatically push our company's contacts to everyone's mailbox (around 60-70 contacts to 60-70 mailboxes) We use Office 365.
They also want the contacts to sync to mobile phones, so I cannot used a shared contact list. It seems only the MAIN contact list can sync to a phone.

So far I have used this:

```
import-contactlist -csv -csvdata ([system.io.file]::readallbytes("PATH TO CSV FILE")) -identity USER
```

This works just fine, but if there are any changes to the CSV and I run it again, it just doubles all the contacts instead of overwriting. Is there anyway I can overwrite the contacts?

I have also tried this:

```
Search-Mailbox -identity USER -SearchQuery kind:contacts -deletecontent
```

This does delete the contacts I have created in the first place, but if there are any OTHER contacts that users have created, it would delete those as well.
I feel like im headed in the right direction.. can anyone help?

Comment: Sounds like you need to load the CSV file into memory, and then for each user loop through the CSV and search/delete contacts if they already exist. There has to be something you can specify in `-SearchQuery` to look for specific contacts.

Comment: Thanks themadtechnician, I did something similar to your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I think I figured it out. After I import the contacts with:

```
import-contactlist -csv -csvdata ([system.io.file]::readallbytes("PATH TO CSV")) -identity USER
```

I can run this to find and delete each added contact:

```
$tcontacts = get-content PATH TO CSV WITH ONLY NAMES
$zcontacts = get-content PATH TO CSV WITH NAMES OF MAILBOXES YOU WANT TO REMOVE CONTACTS FROM
$ccontacts = "null"
$scontacts = "null"
$xcontacts = "null"
foreach ($ccontacts in $tcontacts) {foreach ($scontacts in $zcontacts) {$xcontacts = $scontacts; Search-Mailbox -identity $xcontacts -SearchQuery kind:'contacts', $ccontacts -deletecontent -force}}
```

I use xcontacts = scontacts because of pointer issues (i think?) but anyway, using $scontacts for the -identity doesnt work.

This is a pretty rough script, and you guys could probably find a shorter one, but it works! Thanks